# symfony multilanguage templates

Tags: php, twig, symfony-2.5

I have the following structure for the css files 
Public 
 - css 
 -- fr
 --- style.css
 -- en
 --- style.css

the css folder include fr and en folders

and I'm including CSS stylesheets in my template like so:

```
{% stylesheets '@AtgNewsBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

so i need to include the fr or en folder as user selection

i tried the following but does not work

```
{% stylesheets '@AtgNewsBundle/Resources/public/css/{app.request.getLocale()}/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}

{% stylesheets '@AtgNewsBundle/Resources/public/css/{{app.request.getLocale()}}/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}

{% stylesheets '@AtgNewsBundle/Resources/public/css/"{{app.request.getLocale()}}"/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
```

any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
{% if app.request.locale=="fr" %}

{% stylesheets '@AtgNewsBundle/Resources/public/css/fr/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}

{% elseif app.request.locale=="en" %}

{% stylesheets '@AtgNewsBundle/Resources/public/css/en/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the right [concatenate operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators):

```
{% stylesheets '@AtgNewsBundle/Resources/public/css/' ~ app.request.getLocale() ~ '/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
```

If you prefer to do [string interpolation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#string-interpolation) (less readable IMHO), you should use:

```
{% stylesheets '@AtgNewsBundle/Resources/public/css/#{app.request.getLocale()}/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Can you give technical details?

Comment: Unexpected token "operator" of value "~"
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Syntax